# WatiN c# Validation of page for multiple content

Tags: c#, watin

Just wondering how best to validate a page using WatiN for multiple occurrences of content.

For example I have a page where address details are added. Most fields on that page are mandatory. If I go into that page without populating all mandatory fields and hit the "save" button, I expect 4 "This is a required field." error messages to appear.

Currently I understand how to handle a single error message - something like

> // ASSERTION1
>
> boolVerifyifTextPresent1 = ie.ContainsText("This is a required field.");

and then a

> Assert.IsTrue(boolVerifyifTextPresent1, @"The WebPage does not contain the expected text > ""This is a required field."".");

So what I am after is a way to check that all 4 "this is a required fields" messages appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out the details of how your page content is being generated, but say you were using ASP.net web forms and required field validators.  You would assign IDs to those validators when designing the page and they would be rendered out in HTML as spans with those IDs.  You can then use WATIN to grab that validator span and check its attributes and/or text content.

You could do something similar if you were checking a validation summary, or using MVC.  One way or another, you can grab the element that the error message is in.

```
// do this for each rfv
WatiN.Core.Span rfvAddress1Line1 = Document.Span("ctl00_Container_rfvAddress1Line1");
Assert.IsTrue(rfvAddress1Line1.Exists);
Assert.AreEqual("Some Error Message", rfvAddress1Line1.Text);

// alternatively, if all of the messages were the exact same, you could do this
var spans = Document.Spans.Where(s => s.Text == "Some Error Message");
Assert.AreEqual(4, spans.Count());
```

WATIN is very powerful and you can get very granular in what you test on the page.
I hope this helps.